# Is it possible to make a dialog box end a script?

Tags: java, android

I'm making an app for my programming class using eclipse and I've tried different things to figure out how to make the script stop running. I'm thinking it will be an if statement to close it, but i can't figure it out.

What I'm doing:

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "do you plan on attending a local technology center?");
```

When I use that code it pops up a dialog box saying "yes" "no" "cancel". How could I make the script stop running when the user clicks "no" "cancel" or even the X in the top right of the box? I do not know what code to use.

Comment: What you mean by script? Why the tag c#? why the tag html? aniway this.finish();
Process.killProcess( Process.myPid() ); should close an application in android

Comment: thank you, sorry im new to stackoverflow, so i thought someone from c# or html might know. and by script i mean when they hit "no" cancel" x" it will stop the program from continuing. because when i click anything on the dialog box it continues the program.

Comment: That's not how tags work. You tag a question with the subjects the question is about, not with the "fields of programmers" who might help. I removed the tags for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use `JOptionPane` `Dialog Box` as follow

```
int dialogButton= JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION;
int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Your Message", "Dialog box title",dialogButton);
if(dialogResult==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
//Code for YES Button Clicked
}
else if(dialogResult==JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
{
//Code for NO Button Clicked
}
else if(dialogResult==JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){
//Code for CANCEL Button Clicked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the nuclear option: System.exit(0);

Move activity to background: moveTaskToBack(true);