# Cannot use this in a static context and myPid() is undefined for the type of Process

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a dialog box that will close when the user clicks no or cancel, and that the script will continue when they hit yes, but for some reason i can not get the code below to work.

```
this.finish(); Process.killProcess( Process.myPid() );


//default title and icon
    int dialogButton= JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION;
    int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "do you plan on attending a local technology center?", "Info",dialogButton);
    if(dialogResult==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
    //Code for YES Button Clicked
    }
    else if(dialogResult==JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
    {
    //Code for NO Button Clicked
         this.finish(); Process.killProcess( Process.myPid() );
    }
    else if(dialogResult==JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){
    //Code for CANCEL Button Clicked
         this.finish(); Process.killProcess( Process.myPid() );
    }
```

Comment: You clearly copied information from your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18722312/is-it-possible-to-make-a-dialog-box-end-a-script, without understanding it. Why did you not ask the commenter to clarify instead of asking another question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the title, I assume you are getting a compile error.

The code you posted is likely in a `static` method.

You cannot use the `this` keyword in a `static` method, because `this` refers to an `object`. When you are running a `static` method you are running on a class level, you call the method for the class and not on an object. The `this` keyword is nonsense here.

FIX: Declare your method `finish` to also be static, and remove the `this`.